# How are sketches like this drawn?

Tags: drawing, technique-identification, sketching

Are these sketches simply drawn by hand with a lot of effort or is there a trick to them?

[image]

Credit: Naruto, Vol. 1: Uzumaki Naruto (9781569319000)

([Version with higher resolution](https://64.media.tumblr.com/9a23acbd3985c8bbda16255b1b46b1b2/d7b3d29ef02e3430-9d/s1280x1920/4ab37400b92071c1d0d506f34884eb58d13c2bf9.jpg))

Answer (score 4):

One way I think is common among comic artists is through **instancing**<sup>*</sup>: after having drawn a few of the figures in different positions, you can copy instances of these individual figures unto the panel using either

- a lightbox or [light table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Light_table), when working with traditional tools, or
- image editing software (e.g. Photoshop or Clip Studio Paint), when taking a digital approach.
- Alternatively, some specialized software allows for importing 3D models that can be positioned, after which a render can be made that looks like a drawing.

However, at close inspection, **this particular image doesn't show obvious signs of instancing**, so I think this was all drawn by hand by Kishimoto.
That, or the instances were edited afterward (using any of the approaches mentioned).

---

<sup>* I'm not sure 'instancing' is the term used in the comic world, though: I know it from 3D editing software and game engines, [where it is common](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometry_instancing).</sup>

Comment: Perhaps it would worth addressing the medium too, like, if not done digitally, then probably done by applying ink with some sort of device, like a technical pen or marker? Also, mentioning that perhaps a pencil pre/under-drawing was employed?

Comment: @Levente Do you mean to describe in more detail the processes required?

Comment: Well, to be honest I focused too much on the title and the image, and I missed the nuance in the line right above the image. So you are right, the things I suggested are not the info OP was after. (However, pre-drawing with a pencil makes the task way less intimidating than the final piece may make it appear, so it could be counted as part of a "trick".)